# LINQ to entities ... without the entities (if possible)

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

Sounds daft i know but i want to do something a bit out of the ordinary ...

essentially I'm looking to build  solution that has a wcf data service at the back end (or something of that ilk at least) that allows me to query my database using simple url syntax.

the problem i have is that when my db schema changes i have to recomile the entire back end and that's not good because the solution i'm building allows the definition of "entities" so to speak.

Essentially what i want to do is have the model update every time the db updates ... as a sort of triggered event.

I'm thinking that EF won't do this which leads me to my actual question ...

How would you solve this problem?

I need exactly what a wcf data service offers out of the box ... just with a more dynamic data model beneath it.

Comment: Linq to entities without entities = ...Linq?

Comment: You can have some code generator to create EDMX or code (Code-First scenario). But code using this is still hardcoded and needs to change, so i do not see your point.

Comment: @Dani Linq to entities without entities = Linq to :)

Comment: lol yeh ... couldn't think of a clean way to explain it but essentially its the fact that you cant change the EF model at runtime thats tripping me up

Comment: Your DB Schema changes that often? :?

Comment: its not so much that it changes often ... its more what i'm building allows for it to ... the idea is like a sort of business process designer ... you throw together object definitions on the front end which results in a table being generated at the back end then the app works its magic on the new tables

Comment: @Wardy Of course you can change model on fly. But it is not very common :-)

Comment: @Wardy EF is probably not right choice for your scenario.

Comment: i was kinda thinking that ... both statements really ... any idea of alternatives ?

Comment: the linq results in an entity / typeof(iqueryable) i don't need an object ... simply a lump of xml (if that helps at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the O/RM to something more dynamic ... something like [Massive](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2011/02/16/and-i-shall-call-it-massive) could be used instead of EF.

Someone looks to be doing similar with WebWCF ... [Massive with WCF Web Api to return dynamic types/Expandos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970083/massive-with-wcf-web-api-to-return-dynamic-types-expandos).

If you use data services then you'd need to figure out some way to represent the Massive as a 'DataContext'. WebWCF on the other hand would serialise dynamic objects as a lump of JSON or XML where required.

---

The problem with your proposed approach is one where the Web Service contract is dynamic and not versioned. This means that if you delete/rename/change a field you essentially have created a change to the 'Contract' that the clients use to consume the web service. This can lead to a client **breaking** unless updated at the same time.

If you are looking at a low friction way of managing model change updating database I have found that EF Code First 4.2 and [EF Migrations](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx) works pretty well for me. 0.7.0.1 is reasonably stable and all available from NuGet.

Comment: Interesting ... i see your point but i'm kind of taking the microsoft approach with sharepoint ... create an app that has a db and builds other apps with their own db then users interact with their creations ... accept its more of a workflow type scenario instead of collaboration tooling

Comment: Ok, I'll have a bit more of think :)

Comment: oooo i love this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970083/massive-with-wcf-web-api-to-return-dynamic-types-expandos

Comment: exactly what i'm trying to do